# What determines if str.strip() will work?

Tags: python, string, strip

From the [Python Docs page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for `str.strip()` you find this example.

```
>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')
'example'
```

That works well and fine; but why do these two not do anything?

```
>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('.')
'www.example.com'   

>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('co')
'www.example.com'
```

Comment: Do you know what strip does? Directly from the documentation you posted: "Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed." Is the . and co leading or trailing aka on the start or end?

Comment: Read the docs one more time. :) *Return a copy of the string with the **leading** and **trailing** characters removed.*

Comment: Thanks, it might be nice if the example string had some of those letter on the inside so that we could see those not get affected.

Comment: @cdhagmann it had 'm'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.strip()` strips *from the ends*, so only leading and trailing characters are removed.

Neither example has a `.` or a `c` or `o` at either end.

In the example in the documentation, the text starts with `w`, which is in the set of characters to remove. After removing the `www`, the next character `.` is also in the set of characters to remove. The `e` is not and stripping stops there. At the end of the sample text there is first an `m`, then an `o`, then a `c` and finally a `.` to remove.

To remove specific characters from within a string, use `str.replace()` (for individual characters), a regular expression (for a set), or use `str.translate()`:

```
>>> 'www.example.com'.replace('.', '')
'wwwexamplecom'
>>> 'www.example.com'.translate(None, 'co')
'www.example.m'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[co]', '', 'www.example.com')
'www.example.m'
```

Comment: So what removes characters from within a string then?